# Dynamic Order By using Room

Tags: android, android-sqlite, android-room

I want to create a dynamic query using room so that in one case the query returns a particular order type and during runtime if the order type changes then a new query is created and the data is returned ordered according to this type.

I am returning a DataSource.Factory object using Room.
I am using the below statement to process my query:-

```
if(getSortOrderType().equals(context.getString(R.string.sortByPopular))) {
        dbSortType = "popularity";
    } else {
        dbSortType = "vote_average";
    }

movieLiveData =
            new LivePagedListBuilder<>(MovieDatabase
                    .getMovieDbInstance(context)
                    .getMovieDao().getAllMovies(new
                            SimpleSQLiteQuery("SELECT * FROM main_movie ORDER BY ? DESC",
                            new Object[]{dbSortType})), config)
                    .setBoundaryCallback(movieModelBoundaryCallback)
                    .build();
```

But, **during runtime I see that the data being returned is ordered by the already set Primary Key i.e id** and not according to this type that I am constructing in the above statement.

How to use the statement to return the result sorted by the sort type selected.

The Dao method used is:-

```
@RawQuery(observedEntities = MovieModel.class)
DataSource.Factory<Integer,MovieModel> getAllMovies(SupportSQLiteQuery query);
```

Comment: I suspect that `?` cannot be used in an `ORDER BY` clause.

Answer (score 1):

Okay so, I have found a simple answer to that.

I just replaced the statement -- 
`new SimpleSQLiteQuery("SELECT * FROM main_movie ORDER BY ? DESC",                      new Object[]{dbSortType})`

to this:-

```
new SimpleSQLiteQuery("SELECT * FROM main_movie ORDER BY "+ dbSortType + " DESC"))
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all check that getAllMovies function in your DAO is like this:

```
@RawQuery
    fun getAllMovies(query: SupportSQLiteQuery): List<MainMovie>
```

and if your return type is observable types like liveData, PagingSource, etc. :

```
@RawQuery(observedEntities = [MainMovie::class])
 fun getAllMovies(query: SupportSQLiteQuery): PagingSource<Int, MainMovie>
```

then use this:

```
val myQuery=SimpleSQLiteQuery("SELECT * FROM main_movie ORDER BY "+ dbSortType + " DESC")
getMovieDao(). getAllMovies(myQuery)
```