# Room DB, pass ASC or DESC as param

Tags: android, sqlite, android-room

I have a room database set up. And have the following query (which works fine as is):

```
@Query("SELECT * FROM " + TABLE_REPORT
        + " WHERE " + COLUMN_CLASS_ID + " =:classID"
        + " ORDER BY CASE :orderByColumnName"
        + " WHEN 'maths' THEN maths"
        + " WHEN 'physics' THEN physics"
        + " WHEN 'history' THEN history"
        + " END"
        + " DESC")
List<ResultEntity> getClassResult(long classID, String orderByColumnName); // , String orderBy);
```

I want to uncomment the last line and include the **orderBy** parameter in the function and replace **" DESC"** by **" :orderBy"** so I can have the list sorted by **orderBy** which would be ASC or DESC.

I tried doing what I explained above. But it doesn't seem to work.

Error shown is: *"ASC, BETWEEN, COLLATE, DESC, IN, LIMIT, comma or semicolon expected, found :orderBy"*

How can I get this working? Thanks in advance.

Comment: I do not think that what you want is supported. Room only supports `:...` syntax where SQLite supports `?`, and I do not think that SQLite supports the `ASC`/`DESC` being supplied via `?`.

Comment: I guess you are right, this is not supported yet.
See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51347990/dynamic-order-by-using-room to manage a dynamic  `ORDER BY` by using `@RawQuery` annotation

Comment: @CommonsWare I think that might be a possibility too.

Comment: @GaëtanS seems the guy in the link you provided has a problem with Order By 'Column' issue. My order by query works as expected. The only option I need is to pass in 'ASC' or 'DESC' as I desire while run-time.

Comment: @Nikhil Tambe I know but you can use `@RawQuery` to dynamically change 'ASC' or 'DESC' in your query