# Room DAO Order By ASC or DESC variable

Tags: android, android-room, dao

I'm trying to make a `@Query` function in my `@Dao` interface which has a boolean parameter, `isAsc` to determine the order:

```
@Query("SELECT * FROM Persons ORDER BY first_name (:isAsc ? ASC : DESC)")
List<Person> getPersonsAlphabetically(boolean isAsc);
```

Apparently this isn't allowed. Is there a work around here?

**EDIT:**

It seemed odd to use two queries (below) since the only difference is `ASC` and `DESC`:

```
@Query("SELECT * FROM Persons ORDER BY last_name ASC")
List<Person> getPersonsSortByAscLastName();

@Query("SELECT * FROM Persons ORDER BY last_name DESC")
List<Person> getPersonsSortByDescLastName();
```

Answer (score 68, accepted):

Use `CASE Expression` for **SQLite** to achieve this in **Room DAO**,

```
@Query("SELECT * FROM Persons ORDER BY 
        CASE WHEN :isAsc = 1 THEN first_name END ASC, 
        CASE WHEN :isAsc = 0 THEN first_name END DESC")
List<Person> getPersonsAlphabetically(boolean isAsc);
```

Comment: FYI the sqlite query optimizer will not properly optimize this. It will always generate a temporary B-Tree. This is especially true with the older version of SQLite supplied with android.

Answer (score 15):

Create two queries, one with ASC and one with DESC.

```
@Query("SELECT * FROM Persons ORDER BY last_name ASC")
List<Person> getPersonsSortByAscLastName();

@Query("SELECT * FROM Persons ORDER BY last_name DESC")
List<Person> getPersonsSortByDescLastName();
```

Comment: this seems odd to me, creating two queries where the only difference are the ASC and DESC

Comment: yes, not the solution you were looking for apparently

Answer (score -8):

Why don't you try something like this? I have not tested it.

```
@Query("SELECT * FROM Persons ORDER BY first_name :order")
List<Person> getPersonsAlphabetically(String order);
```

And the logic you suggested should go before you make the query.

Comment: Tried it. Doesn't work. Gives the error: (', '.', ASC, BETWEEN, COLLATE, DESC, IN, LIMIT, comma or semicolon expected, got ':order.  Plus.. this is prone to error due to "ACS" and "DECS". you know

Comment: Are you sure you wrote it well?

Comment: Also this is no more error prone that any other code where you have to write by hand ASC or DESC like in your example....

Comment: it was written well on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/51536310/8322877) and got the same error. IDE readily interprets sql queries and expects reserved sql words after ORDER BY not a variable string. A boolean variable would lessen if not fully eliminate error prone code

Comment: I guess then that what you have asked for can not be done. Sorry to hear that. A boolean may lessen or eliminate error prone code, I agree; but your example and my example works exactly the same because you have to convert from boolean to string. Thats what I mean in my previous comment.

Comment: I like these kind of answers because they're so wrong but teach us what NOT to do! Please do NOT delete this (attempt at an) answer.