# Room database - remove colon from query

Tags: android, database, sqlite, android-room, android-jetpack

I am trying to sort my data by ascending and descending order using room database. So I need to pass those parameter to the DAO.

This is my code:

```
@Query("SELECT * FROM DEVICES_TABLE ORDER BY :sortQuery")
fun sortDatabase(sortQuery: String): Flow<List<DeviceData>>
```

But when I pass `title DESC` as `sortquery` (title is column name), the query becomes:

```
SELECT * 
FROM DEVICES_TABLE 
ORDER BY 'title ASC'
```

I need to remove those single quotes from query for achieving the results. I need to sort with title, price, type etc. both ascending and descending. How can I do that?

Comment: Did you try these approaches? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55297165/room-dao-order-by-asc-or-desc-variable

Comment: I've seen that but i am trying to use this same function for sorting multiple fields by changing the parameters

Comment: You can use the same function and case inside the query. Just follow the accepted answer

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Room DAO Order By ASC or DESC variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55297165/room-dao-order-by-asc-or-desc-variable)

Comment: Vlad L pointed to the right place to get answers