# how to use Android Room Database and query using SQLite's Case Expression

Tags: android, sqlite, android-room

I have a room database which contains the mediastore data with various ColumnInfo  like Title, Dateadded, Composer, Album, artist etc

now the simple mediastore query was ,

`cursor = context.getContentResolver().query(MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, columns(),MediaStore.Audio.Media.IS_MUSIC + " = 1", null, SortOrder);`

`Where SortOrder = MediaStore.Audio.Media.TITLE` etc

**I want to use the same logic to query the Room database where ColumnInfo are**

```
@PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)

public long _Id;
    
public long _SongId;

public String _title;

public String _album;

public long _albumId;

public String _artist;

public long _artistId;

public String _path;

public int _trackNumber;

public long _duration;

public String _year;

public String _composer;

public String _dateAdded;
```

I have looked at  [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55298054/3126760)

basically I want to Query each Column using the name of that Column  and sort using ASC or DESC

how can we do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use something like :-

```
@Query("SELECT * FROM mediaentity ORDER BY " +
        "CASE WHEN lower(:sortByColumn) = lower('_id') AND :sortDirection THEN _id END ASC," +
        "CASE WHEN lower(:sortByColumn) = lower('_id') AND NOT :sortDirection THEN _id END DESC," +
        "CASE WHEN lower(:sortByColumn) = lower('_SongId') AND :sortDirection THEN _SongId END ASC, " +
        "CASE WHEN lower(:sortByColumn) = lower('_SongId') AND  NOT :sortDirection THEN _SongId END DESC," +
        "CASE WHEN lower(:sortByColumn) = lower('_title') AND :sortDirection THEN _title END ASC, " +
        "CASE WHEN lower(:sortByColumn) = lower('_title') AND NOT :sortDirection THEN _title END DESC " +
        // and so on, noting the comma except on the last
        ";"
)
abstract List<MediaEntity> getSortedMediaList(String sortByColumn, boolean sortDirection);
```

- using the in-built SQLite `lower` function could be omitted for both sides of the expression.

Or simpler, but less safe, you could use Something like :-

```
@RawQuery
abstract List<MediaEntity> rawQuery(SupportSQLiteQuery qry);

public List<MediaEntity> getSortedMediaListV2(String sortByColumn, boolean sortDirection) {
    String sortOrder = " ASC ";
    if (!sortDirection) {
        sortOrder = " DESC";
    }
    String query = "SELECT * FROM mediaentity ORDER BY " + sortByColumn + sortOrder;
    return rawQuery(new SimpleSQLiteQuery(query));
}
```

- However, if you pass an incorrect column name then it would fail.

Perhaps consider the following working example that utilises the above and, at the end, shows what happens if an incorrect column name is used:-

```
    db = TheDatabase.getInstance(this);
    dao = db.getAllDao();
    dao.deleteAll();
    dao.insert(new MediaEntity(100,"Breathe","Dark Side of the Moon",100100,"Pink Floyd",100,"path to DSOTM",5,180,"1971","Pink Floyd","2021-10-10"));
    dao.insert(new MediaEntity(99,"Speak to Me","Dark Side of the Moon",100100,"Pink Floyd",100,"path to DSOTM",4,180,"1971","Pink Floyd","2021-10-10"));
    dao.insert(new MediaEntity(98,"On the Run","Dark Side of the Moon",100100,"Pink Floyd",100,"path to DSOTM",3,180,"1971","Pink Floyd","2021-10-10"));
    dao.insert(new MediaEntity(102,"Time","Dark Side of the Moon",100100,"Pink Floyd",100,"path to DSOTM",10,180,"1971","Pink Floyd","2021-10-10"));
    dao.insert(new MediaEntity(97,"The Great Gig in the Sky","Dark Side of the Moon",100100,"Pink Floyd",100,"path to DSOTM",9,180,"1971","Pink Floyd","2021-10-10"));
    dao.insert(new MediaEntity(101,"Money","Dark Side of the Moon",100100,"Pink Floyd",100,"path to DSOTM",8,180,"1971","Pink Floyd","2021-10-10"));
    dao.insert(new MediaEntity(103,"Us and Them","Dark Side of the Moon",100100,"Pink Floyd",100,"path to DSOTM",7,180,"1971","Pink Floyd","2021-10-10"));
    dao.insert(new MediaEntity(96,"Any Colour You Like","Dark Side of the Moon",100100,"Pink Floyd",100,"path to DSOTM",1,180,"1971","Pink Floyd","2021-10-10"));
    dao.insert(new MediaEntity(104,"Brain Damage","Dark Side of the Moon",100100,"Pink Floyd",100,"path to DSOTM",6,180,"1971","Pink Floyd","2021-10-10"));
    dao.insert(new MediaEntity(95,"Eclipse","Dark Side of the Moon",100100,"Pink Floyd",100,"path to DSOTM",2,180,"1971","Pink Floyd","2021-10-10"));

    Log.d("MEDIAINFO","EXTRACT 1 -  ID ascending");
    for(MediaEntity m: dao.getSortedMediaList("_Id",true)) {
        Log.d("MEDIAINFO","ID = " + m._Id + " SongId = " + m._SongId + " Title = " + m._title + " track# = " + m._trackNumber + " Album is " + m._album);
    }
    Log.d("MEDIAINFO","EXTRACT 2 - ID descending");
    for(MediaEntity m: dao.getSortedMediaList("_Id",false)) {
        Log.d("MEDIAINFO","ID = " + m._Id + " SongId = " + m._SongId + " Title = " + m._title + " track# = " + m._trackNumber + " Album is " + m._album);
    }
    Log.d("MEDIAINFO","EXTRACT 3 - Title ascending");
    for(MediaEntity m: dao.getSortedMediaList("_title",true)) {
        Log.d("MEDIAINFO","ID = " + m._Id + " SongId = " + m._SongId + " Title = " + m._title + " track# = " + m._trackNumber + " Album is " + m._album);
    }
    Log.d("MEDIAINFO","EXTRACT 4 - Title descending");
    for(MediaEntity m: dao.getSortedMediaList("_title",false)) {
        Log.d("MEDIAINFO","ID = " + m._Id + " SongId = " + m._SongId + " Title = " + m._title + " track# = " + m._trackNumber + " Album is " + m._album);
    }
    Log.d("MEDIAINFO","EXTRACT 5 - SongId ascending");
    for(MediaEntity m: dao.getSortedMediaList("_SongId",true)) {
        Log.d("MEDIAINFO","ID = " + m._Id + " SongId = " + m._SongId + " Title = " + m._title + " track# = " + m._trackNumber + " Album is " + m._album);
    }
    Log.d("MEDIAINFO","EXTRACT 6 - SongId descending");
    for(MediaEntity m: dao.getSortedMediaList("_SongId",false)) {
        Log.d("MEDIAINFO","ID = " + m._Id + " SongId = " + m._SongId + " Title = " + m._title + " track# = " + m._trackNumber + " Album is " + m._album);
    }

    Log.d("MEDIAINFO","EXTRACT 7 - TrackNumber ascending");
    for(MediaEntity m: dao.getSortedMediaListV2("_tracknumber",true)) {
        Log.d("MEDIAINFO","ID = " + m._Id + " SongId = " + m._SongId + " Title = " + m._title + " track# = " + m._trackNumber + " Album is " + m._album);
    }
    Log.d("MEDIAINFO","EXTRACT 8 - TrackNumber descending");
    for(MediaEntity m: dao.getSortedMediaListV2("_tracknumber",false)) {
        Log.d("MEDIAINFO","ID = " + m._Id + " SongId = " + m._SongId + " Title = " + m._title + " track# = " + m._trackNumber + " Album is " + m._album);
    }

    dao.getSortedMediaList("not a known column", true);
    dao.getSortedMediaListV2("not a known column", true);
```

The Output to the log including :-

```
2021-10-18 11:42:48.938 D/MEDIAINFO: EXTRACT 1 -  ID ascending
2021-10-18 11:42:48.946 D/MEDIAINFO: ID = 1 SongId = 100 Title = Breathe track# = 5 Album is Dark Side of the Moon
2021-10-18 11:42:48.946 D/MEDIAINFO: ID = 2 SongId = 99 Title = Speak to Me track# = 4 Album is Dark Side of the Moon
2021-10-18 11:42:48.946 D/MEDIAINFO: ID = 3 SongId = 98 Title = On the Run track# = 3 Album is Dark Side of the Moon
2021-10-18 11:42:48.946 D/MEDIAINFO: ID = 4 SongId = 102 Title = Time track# = 10 Album is Dark Side of the Moon
2021-10-18 11:42:48.946 D/MEDIAINFO: ID = 5 SongId = 97 Title = The Great Gig in the Sky track# = 9 Album is Dark Side of the Moon
2021-10-18 11:42:48.947 D/MEDIAINFO: ID = 6 SongId = 101 Title = Money track# = 8 Album is Dark Side of the Moon
2021-10-18 11:42:48.947 D/MEDIAINFO: ID = 7 SongId = 103 Title = Us and Them track# = 7 Album is Dark Side of the Moon
2021-10-18 11:42:48.947 D/MEDIAINFO: ID = 8 SongId = 96 Title = Any Colour You Like track# = 1 Album is Dark Side of the Moon
2021-10-18 11:42:48.947 D/MEDIAINFO: ID = 9 SongId = 104 Title = Brain Damage track# = 6 Album is Dark Side of the Moon
2021-10-18 11:42:48.947 D/MEDIAINFO: ID = 10 SongId = 95 Title = Eclipse track# = 2 Album is Dark Side of the Moon
2021-10-18 11:42:48.947 D/MEDIAINFO: EXTRACT 2 - ID descending
2021-10-18 11:42:48.949 D/MEDIAINFO: ID = 10 SongId = 95 Title = Eclipse track# = 2 Album is Dark Side of the Moon
2021-10-18 11:42:48.949 D/MEDIAINFO: ID = 9 SongId = 104 Title = Brain Damage track# = 6 Album is Dark Side of the Moon
2021-10-18 11:42:48.949 D/MEDIAINFO: ID = 8 SongId = 96 Title = Any Colour You Like track# = 1 Album is Dark Side of the Moon
2021-10-18 11:42:48.949 D/MEDIAINFO: ID = 7 SongId = 103 Title = Us and Them track# = 7 Album is Dark Side of the Moon
2021-10-18 11:42:48.949 D/MEDIAINFO: ID = 6 SongId = 101 Title = Money track# = 8 Album is Dark Side of the Moon
2021-10-18 11:42:48.949 D/MEDIAINFO: ID = 5 SongId = 97 Title = The Great Gig in the Sky track# = 9 Album is Dark Side of the Moon
2021-10-18 11:42:48.949 D/MEDIAINFO: ID = 4 SongId = 102 Title = Time track# = 10 Album is Dark Side of the Moon
2021-10-18 11:42:48.949 D/MEDIAINFO: ID = 3 SongId = 98 Title = On the Run track# = 3 Album is Dark Side of the Moon
2021-10-18 11:42:48.949 D/MEDIAINFO: ID = 2 SongId = 99 Title = Speak to Me track# = 4 Album is Dark Side of the Moon
2021-10-18 11:42:48.949 D/MEDIAINFO: ID = 1 SongId = 100 Title = Breathe track# = 5 Album is Dark Side of the Moon
2021-10-18 11:42:48.949 D/MEDIAINFO: EXTRACT 3 - Title ascending
2021-10-18 11:42:48.955 D/MEDIAINFO: ID = 8 SongId = 96 Title = Any Colour You Like track# = 1 Album is Dark Side of the Moon
2021-10-18 11:42:48.955 D/MEDIAINFO: ID = 9 SongId = 104 Title = Brain Damage track# = 6 Album is Dark Side of the Moon
2021-10-18 11:42:48.955 D/MEDIAINFO: ID = 1 SongId = 100 Title = Breathe track# = 5 Album is Dark Side of the Moon
2021-10-18 11:42:48.955 D/MEDIAINFO: ID = 10 SongId = 95 Title = Eclipse track# = 2 Album is Dark Side of the Moon
2021-10-18 11:42:48.955 D/MEDIAINFO: ID = 6 SongId = 101 Title = Money track# = 8 Album is Dark Side of the Moon
2021-10-18 11:42:48.955 D/MEDIAINFO: ID = 3 SongId = 98 Title = On the Run track# = 3 Album is Dark Side of the Moon
2021-10-18 11:42:48.955 D/MEDIAINFO: ID = 2 SongId = 99 Title = Speak to Me track# = 4 Album is Dark Side of the Moon
2021-10-18 11:42:48.955 D/MEDIAINFO: ID = 5 SongId = 97 Title = The Great Gig in the Sky track# = 9 Album is Dark Side of the Moon
2021-10-18 11:42:48.955 D/MEDIAINFO: ID = 4 SongId = 102 Title = Time track# = 10 Album is Dark Side of the Moon
2021-10-18 11:42:48.955 D/MEDIAINFO: ID = 7 SongId = 103 Title = Us and Them track# = 7 Album is Dark Side of the Moon
2021-10-18 11:42:48.956 D/MEDIAINFO: EXTRACT 4 - Title descending
2021-10-18 11:42:48.959 D/MEDIAINFO: ID = 7 SongId = 103 Title = Us and Them track# = 7 Album is Dark Side of the Moon
2021-10-18 11:42:48.959 D/MEDIAINFO: ID = 4 SongId = 102 Title = Time track# = 10 Album is Dark Side of the Moon
2021-10-18 11:42:48.959 D/MEDIAINFO: ID = 5 SongId = 97 Title = The Great Gig in the Sky track# = 9 Album is Dark Side of the Moon
2021-10-18 11:42:48.959 D/MEDIAINFO: ID = 2 SongId = 99 Title = Speak to Me track# = 4 Album is Dark Side of the Moon
2021-10-18 11:42:48.959 D/MEDIAINFO: ID = 3 SongId = 98 Title = On the Run track# = 3 Album is Dark Side of the Moon
2021-10-18 11:42:48.960 D/MEDIAINFO: ID = 6 SongId = 101 Title = Money track# = 8 Album is Dark Side of the Moon
2021-10-18 11:42:48.960 D/MEDIAINFO: ID = 10 SongId = 95 Title = Eclipse track# = 2 Album is Dark Side of the Moon
2021-10-18 11:42:48.960 D/MEDIAINFO: ID = 1 SongId = 100 Title = Breathe track# = 5 Album is Dark Side of the Moon
2021-10-18 11:42:48.960 D/MEDIAINFO: ID = 9 SongId = 104 Title = Brain Damage track# = 6 Album is Dark Side of the Moon
2021-10-18 11:42:48.960 D/MEDIAINFO: ID = 8 SongId = 96 Title = Any Colour You Like track# = 1 Album is Dark Side of the Moon
2021-10-18 11:42:48.960 D/MEDIAINFO: EXTRACT 5 - SongId ascending
2021-10-18 11:42:48.965 D/MEDIAINFO: ID = 10 SongId = 95 Title = Eclipse track# = 2 Album is Dark Side of the Moon
2021-10-18 11:42:48.965 D/MEDIAINFO: ID = 8 SongId = 96 Title = Any Colour You Like track# = 1 Album is Dark Side of the Moon
2021-10-18 11:42:48.965 D/MEDIAINFO: ID = 5 SongId = 97 Title = The Great Gig in the Sky track# = 9 Album is Dark Side of the Moon
2021-10-18 11:42:48.966 D/MEDIAINFO: ID = 3 SongId = 98 Title = On the Run track# = 3 Album is Dark Side of the Moon
2021-10-18 11:42:48.966 D/MEDIAINFO: ID = 2 SongId = 99 Title = Speak to Me track# = 4 Album is Dark Side of the Moon
2021-10-18 11:42:48.966 D/MEDIAINFO: ID = 1 SongId = 100 Title = Breathe track# = 5 Album is Dark Side of the Moon
2021-10-18 11:42:48.966 D/MEDIAINFO: ID = 6 SongId = 101 Title = Money track# = 8 Album is Dark Side of the Moon
2021-10-18 11:42:48.966 D/MEDIAINFO: ID = 4 SongId = 102 Title = Time track# = 10 Album is Dark Side of the Moon
2021-10-18 11:42:48.967 D/MEDIAINFO: ID = 7 SongId = 103 Title = Us and Them track# = 7 Album is Dark Side of the Moon
2021-10-18 11:42:48.967 D/MEDIAINFO: ID = 9 SongId = 104 Title = Brain Damage track# = 6 Album is Dark Side of the Moon
2021-10-18 11:42:48.967 D/MEDIAINFO: EXTRACT 6 - SongId descending
2021-10-18 11:42:48.971 D/MEDIAINFO: ID = 9 SongId = 104 Title = Brain Damage track# = 6 Album is Dark Side of the Moon
2021-10-18 11:42:48.972 D/MEDIAINFO: ID = 7 SongId = 103 Title = Us and Them track# = 7 Album is Dark Side of the Moon
2021-10-18 11:42:48.972 D/MEDIAINFO: ID = 4 SongId = 102 Title = Time track# = 10 Album is Dark Side of the Moon
2021-10-18 11:42:48.972 D/MEDIAINFO: ID = 6 SongId = 101 Title = Money track# = 8 Album is Dark Side of the Moon
2021-10-18 11:42:48.972 D/MEDIAINFO: ID = 1 SongId = 100 Title = Breathe track# = 5 Album is Dark Side of the Moon
2021-10-18 11:42:48.972 D/MEDIAINFO: ID = 2 SongId = 99 Title = Speak to Me track# = 4 Album is Dark Side of the Moon
2021-10-18 11:42:48.972 D/MEDIAINFO: ID = 3 SongId = 98 Title = On the Run track# = 3 Album is Dark Side of the Moon
2021-10-18 11:42:48.972 D/MEDIAINFO: ID = 5 SongId = 97 Title = The Great Gig in the Sky track# = 9 Album is Dark Side of the Moon
2021-10-18 11:42:48.972 D/MEDIAINFO: ID = 8 SongId = 96 Title = Any Colour You Like track# = 1 Album is Dark Side of the Moon
2021-10-18 11:42:48.973 D/MEDIAINFO: ID = 10 SongId = 95 Title = Eclipse track# = 2 Album is Dark Side of the Moon
2021-10-18 11:42:48.973 D/MEDIAINFO: EXTRACT 7 - TrackNumber ascending
2021-10-18 11:42:48.977 D/MEDIAINFO: ID = 8 SongId = 96 Title = Any Colour You Like track# = 1 Album is Dark Side of the Moon
2021-10-18 11:42:48.978 D/MEDIAINFO: ID = 10 SongId = 95 Title = Eclipse track# = 2 Album is Dark Side of the Moon
2021-10-18 11:42:48.978 D/MEDIAINFO: ID = 3 SongId = 98 Title = On the Run track# = 3 Album is Dark Side of the Moon
2021-10-18 11:42:48.978 D/MEDIAINFO: ID = 2 SongId = 99 Title = Speak to Me track# = 4 Album is Dark Side of the Moon
2021-10-18 11:42:48.978 D/MEDIAINFO: ID = 1 SongId = 100 Title = Breathe track# = 5 Album is Dark Side of the Moon
2021-10-18 11:42:48.979 D/MEDIAINFO: ID = 9 SongId = 104 Title = Brain Damage track# = 6 Album is Dark Side of the Moon
2021-10-18 11:42:48.979 D/MEDIAINFO: ID = 7 SongId = 103 Title = Us and Them track# = 7 Album is Dark Side of the Moon
2021-10-18 11:42:48.979 D/MEDIAINFO: ID = 6 SongId = 101 Title = Money track# = 8 Album is Dark Side of the Moon
2021-10-18 11:42:48.979 D/MEDIAINFO: ID = 5 SongId = 97 Title = The Great Gig in the Sky track# = 9 Album is Dark Side of the Moon
2021-10-18 11:42:48.980 D/MEDIAINFO: ID = 4 SongId = 102 Title = Time track# = 10 Album is Dark Side of the Moon
2021-10-18 11:42:48.980 D/MEDIAINFO: EXTRACT 8 - TrackNumber descending
2021-10-18 11:42:48.984 D/MEDIAINFO: ID = 4 SongId = 102 Title = Time track# = 10 Album is Dark Side of the Moon
2021-10-18 11:42:48.985 D/MEDIAINFO: ID = 5 SongId = 97 Title = The Great Gig in the Sky track# = 9 Album is Dark Side of the Moon
2021-10-18 11:42:48.985 D/MEDIAINFO: ID = 6 SongId = 101 Title = Money track# = 8 Album is Dark Side of the Moon
2021-10-18 11:42:48.985 D/MEDIAINFO: ID = 7 SongId = 103 Title = Us and Them track# = 7 Album is Dark Side of the Moon
2021-10-18 11:42:48.985 D/MEDIAINFO: ID = 9 SongId = 104 Title = Brain Damage track# = 6 Album is Dark Side of the Moon
2021-10-18 11:42:48.985 D/MEDIAINFO: ID = 1 SongId = 100 Title = Breathe track# = 5 Album is Dark Side of the Moon
2021-10-18 11:42:48.985 D/MEDIAINFO: ID = 2 SongId = 99 Title = Speak to Me track# = 4 Album is Dark Side of the Moon
2021-10-18 11:42:48.985 D/MEDIAINFO: ID = 3 SongId = 98 Title = On the Run track# = 3 Album is Dark Side of the Moon
2021-10-18 11:42:48.985 D/MEDIAINFO: ID = 10 SongId = 95 Title = Eclipse track# = 2 Album is Dark Side of the Moon
2021-10-18 11:42:48.985 D/MEDIAINFO: ID = 8 SongId = 96 Title = Any Colour You Like track# = 1 Album is Dark Side of the Moon
```

- The last line line `dao.getSortedMediaListV2("not a known column", true);` fails due to the incorrect column name (the previous line doesn't fail but the result's order probably not be as expected due to the incorrect column name being passed). The exception (as excpected) being

:-

```
2021-10-18 11:42:48.989 E/SQLiteLog: (1) near "known": syntax error
2021-10-18 11:42:48.989 D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
2021-10-18 11:42:48.992 E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: a.a.so69602045javaroomsortbycolumnsviacase, PID: 17538
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{a.a.so69602045javaroomsortbycolumnsviacase/a.a.so69602045javaroomsortbycolumnsviacase.MainActivity}: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: near "known": syntax error (code 1 SQLITE_ERROR): , while compiling: SELECT * FROM mediaentity ORDER BY not a known column ASC
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2913)
```

**Additional**

A third Method would be to have individual Dao's called by method (perhaps in the @Dao class as is the case below) that selects the appropriate Dao e.g. :-

```
/* Method 3 */
@Query("SELECT * FROM mediaentity ORDER BY _id ASC")
abstract List<MediaEntity> getALlOrderBy_Id_ASC();
@Query("SELECT * FROM mediaentity ORDER BY _id DESC")
abstract List<MediaEntity> getALlOrderBy_Id_DESC();

@Query("SELECT * FROM mediaentity ORDER BY _SongId ASC")
abstract List<MediaEntity> getALlOrderBy_SongId_ASC();
@Query("SELECT * FROM mediaentity ORDER BY _SongId DESC")
abstract List<MediaEntity> getALlOrderBy_SongId_DESC();

@Query("SELECT * FROM mediaentity ORDER BY _title ASC")
abstract List<MediaEntity> getALlOrderBy_title_ASC();
@Query("SELECT * FROM mediaentity ORDER BY _title DESC")
abstract List<MediaEntity> getALlOrderBy_title_DESC();

@Query("SELECT * FROM mediaentity ORDER BY _trackNumber ASC")
abstract List<MediaEntity> getALlOrderBy_trackNumber_ASC();
@Query("SELECT * FROM mediaentity ORDER BY _trackNumber  DESC")
abstract List<MediaEntity> getALlOrderBy_trackNumber_DESC();

/* and so on */

public List<MediaEntity> getSortedMediaListV3(String sortbyColumn, boolean sortDirection) {
    List<MediaEntity> rv = new ArrayList(){};
    if (sortDirection) {
        switch ( sortbyColumn) {
            case "_Id":
                rv = getALlOrderBy_Id_ASC();
                break;
            case "_SongId":
                rv = getALlOrderBy_SongId_ASC();
                break;
            case "_title":
                rv = getALlOrderBy_title_ASC();
                break;
            case "_trackNumber":
                return getALlOrderBy_trackNumber_ASC();
        }
    } else {
        switch (sortbyColumn) {
            case "_Id":
                rv = getALlOrderBy_Id_DESC();
                break;
            case "_SongId":
                rv = getALlOrderBy_SongId_DESC();
                break;
            case "_title":
                rv = getALlOrderBy_title_DESC();
                break;
            case "_trackNumber":
                rv = getALlOrderBy_trackNumber_DESC();
        }
    }
    return rv;
}
```