# How does Room use sql statement keywords as query parameters?

Tags: android-room

```kotlin
    @Query(
        """
        SELECT * FROM t_article ORDER BY id :order
    """
    )
    fun pagingSource(order: String): PagingSource<Int, Article>
```

I want `order` set `ASC` or `DESC`, but the compiler prompts

`'(', '.', ASC, BETWEEN, COLLATE, DESC, IN, LIMIT, comma or semicolon expected, got ':order'`

How to solve this problem?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Room DAO Order By ASC or DESC variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55297165/room-dao-order-by-asc-or-desc-variable)

Comment: @forpas This provides a solution, but is not optimal. Because this function is provided by sqlite, not by Room. Like I said, allow query parameters to contain sql statement keywords and spliced into strings.

Comment: This is not allowed. You can use named parameters only to pass literal values and not SQL keywords or even table/column names.

Comment: @forpas So this creates a problem. To achieve this requirement through SQL statements, compared with directly splicing strings, it increases the complexity of the code. And this basic need, I believe many people should have encountered it, can you tell me how you solved it?

Comment: Read the upvoted answers in the duplicate link.

Comment: @forpas I already know what you mean, thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is that you can only bind *(replace ? with a value)* literal values, not KEYWORDS or component names. In short if bound then the values are suitably enclosed so binding the string `ASC` would result in `'ASC'`

You basically have the following options.

a) Multiple `@Query`s with selection of the appropriate Query (ascending or descending) e.g.

```
@Query("SELECT * FROM t_article ORDER BY id ASC")
fun pagingSourceAsc(): PagingSource<Int, Article>

@Query("SELECT * FROM t_article ORDER BY id DESC")
fun pagingSourceDesc(): PagingSource<Int, Article>

fun pagingSource(order: String): PagingSource<Int, Article> {
    if(order.equals
}
```

b) Manipulation according to a value passed to the query where the keywords are selected according to the selection criteria e.g.

```
@Query("SELECT * FROM t_articale ORDER BY WHEN :order = 'ASC' THEN id ASC ELSE id DESC  END")
```

c) By using a `@RawQuery`, which is very flexible BUT not validated at compile time e.g.

```
@RawQuery
fun pagingSourceRawQuery(rawQuery: SupportSQLiteQuery): PagingSource<Int, Article>
fun pagingSource(order: String): PagingSource<Int,Article> {
    return pagingSourceRawQuery(SimpleSQLiteQuery("SELECT * FROM t_artical ORDER BY $order"))
}
```

- Noting that Room will not validate the SQL at compile time and also that as the `order` is not bound then there is the potential for SQL injection.
- this option can eliminate complex SQL but for the sake of the complexity being moved to the programming code (and thus often more understandable).